# Are questions about configuration files on-topic?

Tags: discussion

<s>[The question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/223460/20756)</s> I'd like to ask is about a Nginx configuration file. If the question is not on-topic here where do those kind of questions belong to?

**Update:** The question was moved [here](https://serverfault.com/q/974286/443772)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very common to ask about nginx configuration here, and I don't see a problem with asking your question.